2-way interaction with emtrends or emmeans for a continues and categorical variable
I have a dataset with a continuous outcome variable (curiosity) and three independent variables: age and accuracy (both categorical with two levels), and confidence that has a linear and quadratic term. Here is a sample dataset similar to mine (id is subject number):
 set.seed(300)
df<-data.frame(
  id=rep(c(1:10), each=100),
  confidence=sample(1000, 100, replace=TRUE),
  curiosity=sample(1000, 100, replace=TRUE),
  age=as.factor(rep(c(1:2), each=500)),
  accuracy=as.factor(sample(c(1,2), replace=TRUE, size=1000))
  )


df <- df %>%
  polypoly::poly_add_columns(confidence, degree = 2, prefix = "c", scale_width = 101)

Say, I fit a hierarchical Bayesian regression to this dataset as below (here I set the chain and iter low for the matter of simplicity and speed)
reg_model = brm(curiosity~(c1+c2)*age*accuracy+
                ((c1 + c2) * accuracy | id),
                data=df,
                chains = 1, iter = 500)

Which gives me the following results.
describe_posterior(
  reg_model,
  test = "pd", ci = 0.95, centrality = "mean",
  effects = "fixed", diagnostic = NULL, dispersion = TRUE
) %>%
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(pd = percent(pd, .01)) %>%
  kbl(digits = 2,
      caption = "Parameters of the original model") %>% 
  kable_classic(html_font = "Arial", full_width = FALSE)


As you can see there is no significant interaction in this example. But, imagine that the interaction between accuracy and c1 is significant. Therefore, I want to follow up this interaction and see how c1 slope differs for correct (accuracy=1) vs incorrects (accuracy=2). That is, I want to see slop of c1 for incorrects, minutes slope of c1 for corrects. I used emtreand and emmeans but I always get three-way interaction results. This is what I have tried.
emm <- emtrends(
  reg_model,
  var = "c1", by = c("accuracy"),
  at = list(confidence1 = 0, c2 = -32.9)
)
describe_posterior(
  emm,
  test = "pd", ci = 0.95, centrality = "mean", dispersion = TRUE
) %>%
  bind_rows(
    describe_posterior(
      pairs(emm),
      test = "pd", ci = 0.95, centrality = "mean", dispersion = TRUE
    )  
  ) %>% 
  mutate(pd = percent(pd, .01)) %>%
  kbl(digits = 2,
      caption = "linear trend contrasts") %>% 
  kable_classic(html_font = "Arial", full_width = FALSE)

Which gives me this

As you can see, this table includes age as well. Is there a way to resolve this? I very much appreciate any help.

I don't see how your emtrends() call can work because there is no specs argument. Did you really have "age" as the second argument? That, plus var = "c1" and by = "accuracy" is specifying a breakdown by three factors. In any case, you need to use these functions as they are documented. It also doesn't help that you pipe emm into some other steps without ever looking at emm itself, thus you do not see the helpful annotations that are provided. See ? untidy

PS if you wanted the slopes for c1 for each accuracy, the correct call is emtrends(reg_model, "accuracy", var = "c1").

@RussLenth nails it as usual
